# Is it possible to have a Dataproc cluster auto scale down to 0 workers when no jobs are running?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I know it's best practice to delete a cluster when not in use and spin one up when it's time to run jobs, but I'm wanting to know if we can have a 'cluster' running 24/7, but spin down all workers when there are no jobs running (or after a period of no activity), then auto scale up again when a job is started?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. You can have zero workers only with single node clusters, but they cannot have autoscaling policies. An autoscaling cluster has to have at least 2 primary workers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in Hadoop, but AFAIK, it's for a distributed storage and processing. The fact is, if you scale to 0, you lost your storage.

In this case, it's better to [delete your cluster automatically](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scheduled-deletion) and to automate its creation (with Terraform for example).